# Python Tkinter Liquid Layout with grid

Tags: python, layout, tkinter, grid, tkinter-canvas

I have a small UI created with Python and Tkinter; The window of my application change dimension based on some variable that I set-up but some time I get from the DB too many information and get a bit complex and not very optimized to use to many cases with different dimension based on the result that I have.

So, is it possible to have a liquid layout in the way that the window dimension adapts to content?
I want just specify that I'm using a lot of grid and a canavas.

Thanks so much,
Carlo

Comment: sorry I miss spell DB (Data base); because I retrieve information from the DB and some of them I introduce in a table inside of a canavas but I don't get to have it of dynamic layout so the window is more or less dynamic but the canavas not (temporary I solved with a scroll bar but I don't like this solution).

Comment: Do you need to see the data all at once or would a Scrollbar Widget suffice your needs? Then your UI would not change that much but you can display all data using the scrollbar and would not have to worry about Large Data packets that would be too much to display for your screen

Comment: I want that horizontally the window will adapt to the test instead vertically can be a scroll, the problem is that once that I set-up a scroll take a vertical and horizontal one.